# Incorrect results in joining two tables

Tags: sql-server, join, datagridview

Following is the SQL query that is giving incorrect results.

```
Select  ASXCode.Stock_Code, Count(Bought.Number_Bought) as Transactions, 
        SUM(Bought.Number_Bought) as Bought,
        SUM(Bought.Total_Cost) / SUM(Bought.Number_Bought) AS Average_Price,
        SUM(Bought.Acc_Interest) as Interest,
        SUM(Income.Total_Income) / COUNT(Bought.Number_Bought) as Derived_Income,  
        Sum(Bought.Total_Cost + Bought.Acc_Interest + Income.Neg_Total_Income) / SUM(Bought.Number_Bought) as Breakeven
FROM 
    ASXCode 
  LEFT JOIN 
    Bought ON Bought.Stockid = ASXCode.Stockid
  LEFT JOIN 
    Income ON ASXCode.Stockid = Income.Incomeid
GROUP BY 
    ASXCode.Stock_Code
```

The above SQL query results in a DataGridview as follows:

```
 Stock_Code|Transactions|Bought|Average_Price|Interest|Derived_Income| Breakeven   
      ASL         2      10000      0.45       15.00                                                                           
      RCR         2       5000      1.90       55.35   
      SKE         6      20000      1.27      148.97    1071.43        0.96
```

There are two problems with this table. Total income has been multiplied by the number of transactions in calculating the breakeven price. The correct breakeven price is about 1.22. This part of the query could be fixed if I could add “divide by the sum of COUNT Number_Rows”. However I have been unsuccessful in including this in the query.  Secondly, since there is no income for the other two holdings the income fields are Null and I think this makes it impossible to calculate a breakeven price.  I thought this problem might be solved by including in the query “where income is not null”.  However, despite making various attempts at including such a statement in the query I have drawn a blank.  I would really like to think there is a solution to my problems.

Comment: Have a look at what the query returns without aggregates and group by.

Comment: Also, is joining stockid on incomeid actually what you want? What are the cardinalities? - Add a small sample dataset.

Comment: I think I could offer a better solution if I knew the schema of Income, but I will guess there is a single line item for a given stockid, correct?  if that is the case, create a CTE with same query, but exclude references to Income.  Then, join the CTE to Income.  That will solve the first problem.

Comment: I am a complete newby to this and your expression CTE is the first time I have heard it.  A quick Google search has provided brief info and I will look at this further.  The ASXCode table is connected to the Bought table and the income table.  I have uploaded the schema at the following link:     Inchttps://www.flickr.com/photos/133286229@N02

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from where you have a main table and two details table like this:

```
[ Bought ] *-------1 [ ASXCode ] 1-------* [ Income ]
```

So, when you need a result base on `ASXCode` and detailed on `Bought` without any crossing to `Income` and vise-versa; you need a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ASXCode AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT *
     FROM Bought
     GROUP BY *) AS B ON A.PK = B.FK
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT *
     FROM Income
     GROUP BY *) AS I ON A.PK = I.FK
```

So, For you I think this query should work correctly:

```
SELECT
    A.Stock_Code, 
    B.Count_Number_Bought as Transactions, 
    B.SUM_Number_Bought as Bought,
    B.SUM_Total_Cost / B.SUM_Number_Bought AS Average_Price,
    B.SUM_Acc_Interest as Interest,
    I.SUM_Total_Income / B.Count_Number_Bought as Derived_Income,  
    (B.SUM_Total_Cost + B.SUM_Acc_Interest + I.SUM_Neg_Total_Income) / B.SUM_Number_Bought as Breakeven
FROM 
    ASXCode AS A
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         Bought.Stockid,
         COUNT(Bought.Number_Bought) As COUNT_Number_Bought,
         SUM(Bought.Number_Bought) AS SUM_Number_Bought,
         SUM(Bought.Total_Cost) AS SUM_Total_Cost,
         SUM(Bought.Acc_Interest) AS SUM_Acc_Interest
     FROM 
         Bought 
     GROUP BY 
         Bought.Stockid) AS B ON B.Stockid = A.Stockid
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         Income.Stockid,
         SUM(Income.Total_Income) AS SUM_Total_Income,
         SUM(Income.Neg_Total_Income) AS SUM_Neg_Total_Income
     FROM
         Income 
     GROUP BY
         Income.Stockid) AS I ON A.Stockid = I.Stockid
```

Comment: shAt thanks for your information.  You are correct about the structure of the database.  However, your comment about the Income FK  has highlighted (I think) that there is an error in my database construction.  I am now wondering whether my FK's are named incorrectly?  I have uploaded  my database schema to   https://www.flickr.com/photos/133286229@N02/

Comment: @Johnkg I edit my query as your schema, I hope it gives you the correct resulta ;).

Comment: shAt, I forgot to mention that I could not get your query to run and got a message  "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON':" which is what led me to believe there is a problem with my database itself.

Comment: @Johnkg I think it should be removed now ;).

Comment: I have now uploaded (to the same link) my datagridview of the transaction details and a consolidated view of those transactions without the query joining the income table.  I have also uploaded the result of the query solution you provided.  As you will see, the income has been divided by the number of transactions and there is no calculation for transactions that do not have any income.

Comment: Income calc is easily fixed by deleting   { / B.Count_Number_Bought}